# HTML & CSS Cannot separate a DIV from an I

Tags: html, css

I was trying to create a menu bar for a website but stumbled upon a behaviour I did not fully comprehend. Basically I want to have a Font-Awesome icon inside a DIV with another div that contains a header and a paragraph element. To separate the DIV from the FA icon a little bit, I specified a margin to the icon but instead of using the icon as reference it was using the edge of the parent DIV as reference.

HTML:

```
<div class="info-box">
  <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-3x"></i>
  <div class="info-keeper">
    <h3>Mon - Sat: 9:00 - 18:00</h3>
    <p>Sunday closed</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#first-row .infos .info-box {
  float:left;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
#first-row .infos .info-keeper{
  padding-right: 15px;
}
#first-row .infos .info-box h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top:0px; /*because of bootstrap h3 */
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
#first-row .infos .info-box i {
 float:left;
 padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Does anybody have an idea of how to create space between the icon and the DIV?

UPDATE: 
I want to have them spaced horizontally!

Comment: Definitely edit your question so it clarifies whether you want the icon and text aligned horizontally or vertically, cheers.

Comment: your CSS references HTML that isn't in your post. I this what you have currently? What's wrong with it? Looks like there is space to me https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVjxGw

Comment: By default a div will start on a new line by itself. If you want it to flow with the text you should change its display to inline-block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain more? If I'm thinking corretly you want to try -

```
    #first-row .infos .info-box {
      float:left;
      padding: 5px;
      min-width: 200px;
    }
    #first-row .infos .info-keeper {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
    #first-row .infos .info-box h3 {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-top:0px; /*because of bootstrap h3 */
      margin-bottom:5px;
    }
    #first-row .infos .info-box i {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     margin-right: 15px;
    }
```

Vertical align top, middle, bottom as you'd like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

inline lists are great for lining up content and icons, see my attached example.

Note I have stripped out your classes and styles to show the point, but you can bring back whatever you want, just know I've added padding to the list elements in this case; you can adjust these to suit.

```css
.inline-list {
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding: 0;
}

.inline-list p,
.inline-list h3 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.inline-list li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="info-box">
<ul class="inline-list">
<li><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-3x"></i></li>
<li><h3>Mon - Sat: 9:00 - 18:00</h3>
    <p>Sunday closed</p></li>
</ul>
  

    

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing it up! That is another nice solution!

Comment: You're welcome, I, and many Front Enders, use this one to manage situations like this. :)